# How do I Change the Sheet Name from C# on an Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: c#, excel

I have a C# application where I am creating numerous Excel Files from Data in a Database. This part is working fine.  However, my user asked if the sheet tab could be modified to reflect a field from the database.  This sounds simple, however, when I try to reset the name, it tells me that it is read only and cannot be set.  I have tried the following and it has not worked:

```
xlApp.Sheets[0].Range["A1"].Value = "NewTabName";
```

ALSO TRIED:

```
xlApp.Name = "NewTabName";
```

I did a google search and saw some other approaches which did not work for me as well.  And a few responses indicated that it is readonly and could not be done.

This seems like something that should be simple.  How can I do it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to get access to the actual worksheet.  Try something like:

```
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Worksheet)xlApp.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
  worksheet.Name = “NewTabName”;
```

Comment: This is wrong anwser! Sheet1 will not exists if client has diffrent Language verision! For example In Polish this string would be "Arkusz1" instead of Sheet1

Comment: This right answer, You need to change the code as per your needs, If you are not sure what will be the sheet name ,pass the sheet index instead of sheet name,so short you can pass 1 instead of  "Sheet1" or "Arkusz1"

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fairly complete example I am copying in from existing code.

Works perfectly on Windows 10 with Excel from Office 365

Ensure you add a reference to -
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

My path for this DLL (may differ depending on office version) -
C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll

```
// Add this at top of C# file -
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

// In your class or function -
private static Excel.Application XlApp = null;
private static Excel.Workbook XlWorkbook = null;

// In your function -
XlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();

// Load workbook
XlWorkbook = XlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"Filename.xls",
    0, false, Type.Missing, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows,
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing, true, Type.Missing,
    Type.Missing);

// Get reference to sheet
XlWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)XlWorkbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
                        
int numsheets = XlWorkbook.Sheets.Count;

// iterates through all sheets (1-n inclusive, not zero based)
for(int i=1;i<=numsheets;i++)
{
    Excel.Worksheet sht = (Excel.Worksheet)XlWorkbook.Worksheets[i];
    
    // Show sheet name
    Console.WriteLine(i+" "+sht.Name);
}

// To save with a same or different filename
XlWorkbook.SaveAs(@"Filename.xls",
    Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, "",
    "", false, false,
    Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing,
    true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

// Close Excel  
XlWorkbook.Close(true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
XlApp.Quit();

// Ensure you release resources
releaseObject(XlApp);
releaseObject(XlWorkbook);
releaseObject(XlWorksheet);
```

Separate function called from above

```
private static void releaseObject(object obj)
{
  // try .. catch
  System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
}
```